# I want to put small line inside each EditText

Tags: android

I want to add small lines under the Edit Texts like the following , How can I do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by default look of Edittext  in Holo Theme. so just apply Holo Theme.

if you want to apply Holo Theme. set

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

and **styles.XML** inside **values-v11** folder

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

and **styles.XML** inside **values** folder

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>


 <style name="progressbar_holo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
</style>
```

and in **AndroidMeanifeast.xml**

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

in **application** TAG.